# Using python3.6 TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python 3.6 version, I am getting following error:

> TypeError: an integer is required  (invsf['Destn Branch'] =
>   invsf.apply(lambda x: convloc(x['Destn Branch'])))

Code:

```
loclist = ['Destn Branch','Hub SC Location','Origin Branch']
maplist = dict({'MAAG': 'MAAC','NEIR': 'GAUB','RJPR': 'PTLF','SIKM': 'SILB','KLMF':'COKB','AMDE':'AMDO'})
print (loclist)
totalconsinv = len(invsf)

## Check done 
def convloc(location):
    get_dict = maplist.get(location)
    print ('get_dict',get_dict)
    if get_dict is None:
        #print 'location',location
        return location
    else:
        return get_dict


invsf['Destn Branch'] = invsf.apply(lambda x: convloc(x['Destn Branch']))
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: what's `invsf`?

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers:

- You've declared a dict with `{...}`. Calling `dict()` over it is redundant.
- If your apply operation affects one column only, you should call apply on that series.

  ```
  invsf['Destn Branch'] = invsf['Destn Branch'].apply(covloc)
  ```

  This would allow you to get rid of the `lambda`.

---

In your case, however, calling `map` would be more suitable.

```
invsf['Destn Branch'] = invsf['Destn Branch'].map(maplist)
```

Comment: I was about to suggest passing an axis to apply but calling apply for a column is by far the best. :)